# Firefox & iPad 2 (Safari) have extra space in the horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, safari, cross-browser

We are baffled by a horizontal scroll that shows up when you scroll to the bottom of Firefox and on the iPad 2 (running Safari).

In Firefox on both Mac and PC, according to Firebug all elements are the correct size.  yet there is this grey area if you scroll. The scroll bar does not reflect this extra space; you need to access it via a trackpad. On the iPad, the grey space shows up as part of the body. That is, the browser thinks the site is 200 or so pixels wider than it is.  It works correctly on the desktop Safari.

I've gone through every child element and everything fits. Any help would be so appreciated.
!

Thank you!

[Here you can see the grey space we don't want!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2iVv.png)

Comment: Not sure I understand which area you are talking about? Right side next to the images or bottom below the images?

Comment: Both. The site should be full-width with very little space to the right. If you notice where the header and footer backgrounds stop, that is where the site should. Compare to Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully understanding your question either - the image confused more than it helped, but my first suggestion would be in your CSS, set `overflow: hidden` to your body or main container divs.

Comment: Wow. I think that may have worked. So simple and obvious!!  Thanks a million.